# Filestream and CRLF delimiter?

Tags: c#, stream

I have a `Filestream` and i'm reading a **large** File.

The delimiter is `CRLF` and I want to read just until CRLF.

How to do that using Filestream?
Is `Filestream` even the right choice?

i'm NOT interesting in `readallLines` or similar methods, where you have to load all the file into the memory.

The main priority is memory efficiency.

Comment: `File.ReadLines()` doesn't read all the file and so `File.ReadLines(@'C:\MyFile.txt').Take(1)` may be a solution; (note the differece between `ReadAllLines` and `ReadLines`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You comment changes the problem dramatically; so you have an *open* `FileStream` and you want to find the next CRLF `('\r\n')` in it; in that case something like that could be implemented:

```
   private static long GetNextCRLFPosition(FileStream stream) {
     try {
       long savedPosition = fs.Position;

       // ReadByte - we're working with binary file...
       for (int item = fs.ReadByte(); item >= 0; item = fs.ReadByte()) {
         if (item == '\r') {
           item = fs.ReadByte();

           if (item == '\n') 
             return fs.Position - 2;
           else 
             fs.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.Current); 
         }
       }     

       return -1; 
     }
     finally {
       fs.Seek(savedPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     }
   }

   ...  

   using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\MyFile.Text", FileMode.Open)) {
     ...
     // The next "\r\n" is in shift bytes
     long shift = GetNextCRLFPosition(fs);     
     ...
   }
```

Comment: My problem is that my so called binary file contain lots of "text", so i have to interchange between `FileStream` and `StreamReader`. if i read from StreamReader `ReadLines` do i also change the position of the `FileStream`? SomeHow i cant get that to work.

Comment: @RayOldProf StreamReader seems to be just a layer around FileStream and just uses its [FileStream] Position property. So their positions are connected.

Comment: I just found out that is not that simple. `StreamReader` uses some `buffer` and its position is not equal to `FileStream`. therefore i can not use `StreamReader`. any alternative?

Comment: @RayOldProf: `FileStream` uses *buffer* as well, and you can even set it, e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0y914c5(v=vs.110).aspx The *default* buffer size is *4096*.

Comment: its sad that `StreamReader` cant be used. the solution will be much cleaner using `Readlines`. But your solution is also perfect and works.